# Why do Amy's parents dislike Kif?

Tags: futurama

Kif and Amy were set up in the episode "A Flight to Remember" (S1E10) by Amy's parents but in a later episode, "Where the Buggalo Roam" (S3E10) they try to split them up despite Kif saving her life.

**In light of their original endorsement of the relationship, why do the Wongs disapprove of Kif as Amy's boyfriend?**

Answer (score 10):

When the Wongs first set Kif up with Amy, he was actually *captain* of the ship, having been promoted by Zapp just before he fled in an escape pod. This likely made him seem much more respectable to her parents. Later, when they found out he was just a Fourth Lieutenant and Zapp's lackey, he wasn't quite as appealing.

Comment: It certainly doesn't help that his first attempt to save their Buggalos got their daughter captured by native Martians.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if Mr and Mrs Wong have forgotten who Kif is, in between the episodes. When they meet him again, they take an instant dislike because he's a puny, weird-looking alien.

> **Mr. Wong:** *This your boyfriend? I have instant dislike of him!*
>
> **Mrs. Wong:** *He too scrawny to father grandchildren.*
>
> **Amy:** *He's not scrawny, he's just small-boned.*
>
> **Kif:** *Actually, I don't have bones. I'm supported by a system of fluid-filled bladders that--*
>
> **Mr. Wong:** *Yes, yes! You a big squishy wuss! Amy should be dating real man. Like him!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Where the Buggalo Roam](https://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Where_the_Buggalo_Roam)</sup></sub>